# What is a more restful approach?

Tags: spring, rest

Which URL ist better.

/customeradd or customer/add

The thing is I need 2 URL because I have 2 times a GET .

First get is for basically findCustomer by id and Second is for GetCustomer to create a new Customer .

Why this question originally came up is because my thymeleaf could all of a sudden not find the
image when I had a "2 level" URL like /customer/add . Actually I do not understand why.
Normally it was looking for the image in localhost/images/logo.jpg but now all of a sudden it was looking
in localhost/customer/images/logo.jpg  . So somehow it was also referencing the first level.

```
<img th:src="@{/images/logo.jpg}" width="217" height="43" alt=""  >
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need two URLs. You only need `/customer`. Use the same URL with two different HTTP verbs.

- Use `GET` to find a customer.
- Use `POST` to create a customer

look into `REST` as software architectural style.

Comment: POST involves two things. First you need the GET to load the form. After the user filled out the form and submits it  then you will have the POST !!!!

Comment: @Josephine No, that's not true. A form is not required for doing a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

> What is a more restful approach?

REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your URI; so both of the options you listed are fine.

```
/customeradd
/customer/add
/2b85cbe0-c6f3-43b4-b044-b35c31f830f6
```

It's all good; resource identifiers are *identifiers* -- semantically opaque tokens that you can use to identify/fetch/store a resource.  Think: "surrogate key".

It may help to recall as well that resource identifiers identify *resources*; your resource model is a collection of "documents" that you provide as interfaces to your domain model.

So it's perfectly reasonable to have an `/addCustomerForm` identifier for your add customer form, and a `/findCustomerForm` identifier for you find customer form.

There are sometimes mechanical advantages to using a hierarchy of identifiers; it's easy to use relative resolution and dot segments to construct `/customers/addForm` from `/customers/findForm`, and vice versa.

If you are concerned about having form identifiers in the same hierarchy as your identifiers for customer resources, you can move them somewhere else:

```
/forms/customers/add
/forms/customers/find
```

Comment: This is technically correct - it will work regardless of what URL you use. But to design a REST API properly, you should think in terms of resources (the R of REST) and then use HTTP methods to perform create / update / delete etc. actions on those resources. Don't think in terms of operations, or RPC-style calls. That's the opposite of what REST is about. So the answer by Hadronymous is better.